# The requested resource is not available in struts2 when action class is configured in struts.xml

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts2

I've tried to create a new action class and add it to `struts.xml`, the action class successfully get compiled but when I run tomcat it shows The requested resource is not available 404 error on index page itself.

**CreateUser.jsp**

```
<s:form action = "CreateUserAction" >
    <s:textfield name = "name" label = "Name" />
    <s:textfield name = "userName" label = "User Name" />
    <s:submit value = "Register" />
</s:form>
```

**CreateUserAction.java**

```
public String execute() {
    setMessage("Hello " + getUserName());
    return "SUCCESS";
}
```

**Struts.xml**

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="CreateUserAction" class="com.ecommerce.action.CreateUserAction">
    <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Comment: When resource is not available it sends the error with code 404.

Comment: the action class is available in appropriate folder in class and did add it in struts.xml too.i just double checked it..

Comment: If yo can't access the action class then it can't return the resource. It's not necessary to define a `class` attribute to return a result.

Comment: can you explain it breifly because i am new to struts2

Comment: code looks fine, although need to see your web-app structure. Also, why not try a few examples first https://www.google.co.in/search?q=struts2+examples&oq=struts2+examples&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0j69i60j0l2.5419j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actions in Struts2 are mapped to the URLs that are built from the configuration. When the url of the request match the action name and namespace then it is executed, otherwise error code 404 is returned by the dispatcher. Struts2 is implemented as a filter and it's looking for the requests that are mapped in it's configuration. For example if I want it to filter all URLs I will write in `web.xml`

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
  </filter-class>
</filter>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

If you say the error 404 on index page itself, then you should ask yourself which URL corresponds to it and what action is mapped via configuration to that URL. If you need more detailed picture of what configuration is and what URLs you could enter to execute an action install the config-browser plugin.

Answer (score 0):

for the above issue:"The requested resource is not available in struts2 when action class is configured in struts.xml"
I have a suggestion.

Copy and paste all the external jars in in the folder lib(WebContent-->WEB-INF-->lib)
remove all external jars from Build path (Project -->buildpath-->Configure Build path)

I found this solution is working fine for eclipse Luna with Tomacat 7